# Does Sybase DB have Json Parser?

Tags: json, sybase

I need to parse the JSON string in Sybase DB. Is there any option in Sybase, like **XML parser** (OPENXML())?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some XML support but it's a licensed feature i.e. you have to pay extra for it on a per-core basis. See functionality at:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30020.1570/html/xmlb/title.htm

This assumes you mean for Adaptive Server Enterprise as you haven't mentioned which product you're referring to i.e. ASE, IQ or ASA

Comment: It is Sybase ASE

Comment: Then my link above is for Sybase ASE but it's a licensed feature so you'll have to ask your SAP account manager for costs to use it if it's critical.

Comment: is OPENXML() is also a licensed version?

Comment: OPENXML() looks like a SQL Anywhere (ASA) option rather than ASE - two different products.

Comment: Sorry ASA only. Do we have any function like that for JSON?

Comment: can you please let me know that do we have any JSON parser in Sybase ASA.